# Javascript: " != " Operator doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, operator-keyword, behavior

Good evening !

I am facing a strange behavior with my js/jquery, for a simple function where I am retrieving the last ID of a row, in order to check wether or not it's different from the previous one:

```js
oldMsgId = 0;

// Ajax...
currentId = $( ".message_container tr:last" ).attr('id');
checkNewMsg(currentId);
// ... End Ajax.

function checkNewMsg(MsgId) {
 if (MsgId != oldMsgId) {
  var snd_msg = new Audio('sound/msg.wav');
  snd_msg.volume = 0.3;
  snd_msg.play();
 }
 oldMsgId = MsgId ;
}
```

The system works, however, when no new messages are retrieved, which means the latest ID is EQUAL to the old ID, it still execute the condition !

Of course, it will execute once the page is loaded because the oldMsgId is set to 0, but after that by testing with alerts, it has shown that the condition is running as it should not !

It drives me crazy, if someone has a solution I would be glad to hear it :)

EDIT : RESOLVED

```
Well, while using alerts inside the function this time, it appears I have made a huge mistake placing my oldMsgId var inside a loop function (which calls to ajax), so, the variable was reset to 0 everytime and thus made the difference, I'm very sorry xD!
```

Problem resolved, thanks everyone !

Comment: Add 2 alerts displaying the values of MsgId and oldMsgId to the if statement to visually check if the ids are indeed the same.

Comment: `// Ajax... // ...End Ajax` Sure seems like that could be relevant. There isn't enough information in your question to give an answer.

Comment: show more code, without seeing the context for this code it is anyone's guess what problem might be

Comment: oldMsgId is a numeric value. MsgId is a string value. Use checkNewMsg(parseInt(currentId,10)); ans see if that helps.

Comment: You should log the values of the variables instead of blaming `!=` ;) @jeff: it shouldn't matter, because type conversion.

Comment: @jeff Type casting is implicit. The first check `int != string` will always return false, but then the string will be assigned to the `MsgId` and the next check will be `string != string`. The problem is it should be `!==` instead of `!=`. The former is to check if they are identical (which is what we want with strings), the later is to check if they are equal (which will only check the memory location of the strings).

Comment: @TrevinAvery: *"The first check `int != string` will always return false,"* No, if the string is converted to a value different from the int value, it will be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, while viewing with alerts inside the function this time, it appears I have made a huge mistake placing my oldMsgId var inside a loop function (which calls to ajax), I'm sorry xD!

Problem resolved, thanks everyone !